# Nginx Sub-Domain Always Redirecting to root domain

Tags: nginx

I have two Nginx server blocks.  One is for the root domain, we'll call it `myproject.us`, and other for a sub-domain `subdomain.myproject.us`.  For some reason the sub-domain always redirects back to the root domain when I access it via a web browser.  Tools like cURL don't get redirected.

**Root Server Block File**

```
upstream backend  {
  least_conn;

  server 10.132.42.217:3000;
  server 10.132.39.94:3000;
  server 10.132.66.78:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name myproject.us;
  return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name myproject.us;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/myproject/2017/ssl-bundle.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myproject/2017/server.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS:!DH;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:30m;

  client_max_body_size 500M;

  location /static/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /var/www/myproject/myproject/public/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    add_header X-Nginx-Server 'nginx1';
    add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
  }
}
```

**Sub-Domain Server Block File**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name subdomain.myproject.us

    client_max_body_size 500M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        add_header X-Nginx-Server 'nginx1';
        add_header X-Upstream $upstream_addr;
    }
}
```

You'll see that I'm using Nginx to proxy to a few backend servers.  The sub-domain file uses the backend from the root file.  The desired behavior is:

- http://myproject.us -> Redirects to https://myproject.js
- https://myproject.us -> Does the proxy to the upstream backend
- http://subdomain.myproject.us -> Does the proxy to the upstream backend

To head off the obvious question, yes I'm aware that subdomain.myproject.us will be serving the same content as the secured domain, just without the benefit of HTTPS.

Comment: If `subdomain` is redirecting, it will be `backend` that is doing it. You could look at the access log, and use browser tools to analyse the HTTP headers. Also, could this be a stale browser cache?

Comment: This appears to have been a browser caching problem.